# Conditionally positioning fields in Crystal Reports 10

Tags: crystal-reports

I've done a lot of googling and haven't been able to find a solution to my issue.  I have a report that displays the number of calls for different help desk categories/sub categories.  It has the category name and 4 other columns.  When a child category is displayed it indents the whole line, but I want the last 4 columns to stay aligned under their respective labels.  I'm using Crystal Reports 10 and don't see any where to enter a formula to conditionally position the fields for the last 4 columns.  Even if I did see a place to enter a formula I'm not sure how I would determine where to place the fields because the X position for the field doesn't actually change when the line is indented.  The only thing I could think of to handle this is to figure out how many tabs each line is indented and then subtract those from the X position, but I'm not sure how I could tell how far a line has been indented.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: Do you have a screenshow of what it what is happening. You can black out the data

Answer (score 0):

The SAP User Guide actually has quite a bit of information on this. You can set indentation values and you can do a lot of conditional formatting. Check the guide for CR 2011 out [here](http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/cr2011/en/xi4_cr_usergde_en.pdf) and Section 11 is mostly about how to format reports. 11.3.10.9 talks about indentation, but I suggest you browse the whole section 11. And even though it's for CR 2011, it doesn't vary much for other versions.

Hope that helps,

Chris